# how to calculate $25\otimes 40$

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Hey i need to do nim multiplication of numbers:
a) 6 ⊗ 24
b)25 ⊗ 40

I starded with a) and calculate that $6\otimes 24= 96\oplus(6\otimes 8)$ and I dont know how to calculate this to the end. In point b) and dont know how to start

Comment: But how to calculate $25\otimes 40$? I want to multiply, not add and my numbers arent of the form $2^{2^n}$

Comment: The algorithm given there is for all.

Comment: But i want to calculate this by hand, without help of computer

Comment: The algorithm can be done by hand, too. Look up the algorithm.

Comment: I don't know with certain what definition you're working with, but [the multiplication section of the Wikipedia page for Nimber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber#Multiplication) should be helpful - it provides a general definition in terms of mex, facts about what happens with nimbers of the form $2^{2^n}$ you can use to simplify things, and (implicitly) the fact that multiplication distributes over nimber addition. If you try using one or both approaches from Wikipedia and get stuck, and post about your attempt, it would be easier to help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an inefficient method to calculate nim products:

1. Write both factors as a sum of powers of two. (e.g. $14=8+4+2$)
2. Write each power of two in each summation as a product of Fermat $2$-powers, meaning numbers of the form $2^{2^n}$ for some $n\ge 0$. For example, $2^{11}=2^{8+2+1}=2^{2^3}\cdot 2^{2^1}\cdot 2^{2^0}$.
3. Expand out with the distributive property.
4. You now how have a sum of products of Fermat-two powers. If all of the Fermat $2$-powers within each product are distinct, you can simply multiply them as normal, then compute the nim sum of all summands (i.e. canceling equal $2$-powers). Otherwise, find a summand with a repeated Fermat $2$-power $2^{2^n}\otimes 2^{2^n}$, and replace it with the $2^{2^n}+2^{(2^n-1)}$.
5. Return to step $2$.

For example, you wanted to compute $6\otimes 8$. This goes like
$$
\def\x{\otimes}
\begin{align}
6\otimes 8
  &\stackrel{1}=(4+2)\otimes 8
\\&\stackrel{2}=(4+2)\otimes (4\otimes 2)
\\&\stackrel{3}=4\x 4 \otimes 2+2\x4\x2
\\&\stackrel{4}= (4+2)\x 2 + 4\x(2 +1)
\\&\stackrel{3}=4\x 2 + 2\x2+4\x 2+4\x1
\\&\stackrel{4}=4\x 2+(2+1)+4\x 2+4
\end{align}
$$
At this point, all products are of distinct Fermat $2$-powers, so you know what to do.

I can get you started for $(b)$:

$$
\begin{align}
25\otimes 40
  &= (1+8+16)\x(8+32)
\\&= (1+4\x2+16)(4\x 2+16\x2)
\\&= \color{green}{4\x2}+\color{green}{16\x2}+(4\x4\x2\x2)
\\&\;\;+(16\x4\x2\x2)+\color{green}{(16\x4\x2)}+(16\x16\x2)
\end{align}
$$
To simplify things somewhat, note the green summands are "done," because they have been reduced to a product of distinct Fermat $2$-powers. You can then work on each remaining summand separately. For example, the last one:
$$
\begin{align}
(16\x16\x2)
&= (16+8)\x 2
\\&= (16+4\x 2)\x 2
\\&= 16\x 2+4\x 2\x 2
\end{align}
$$
Now the $16\x 2$ part is done, and you work on $4\x 2\x 2$ by expanding $2\x 2$ into $2+1$, and so on. (I said it was inefficient!)